# Full screen in Electron js adds a blank space at the bottom

Tags: html, electron, html5-video

I have an electron desktop app where in some modules there is a functionality to view videos in full screen like this -
[image: Video Modal]
Notice that you can see the top navigation bar and there is no white strip at the bottom

Now after clicking the full screen button here is the UI

[image]
[image]

This also messes up the click targets. now I have to click a little below to where the buttons actually are.